# variable empty when doing an asynchronous call in node.js (closure)

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

Update: Solved, it was indeed a scope issue. I got around it by moving the user list code inside the database class and returning the prebuilt list.

Using node.js, I make an asynchronous call to function findUser and I build a list of users from the callback into the variable content. This works fine during the loop (where it says content variable is available) but when the loop exits, the variable is empty. How can I rewrite the code so that the value of variable content is available outside the loop?

```
exports.listUsers=function(req,res) {
    var content=''
    isLoggedIn=user.findUser({},function(myuser) {
        content =  content +'<li>' + myuser.firstname + ' ' + myuser.lastname + "</li>\n";
           //here value of content var is available
           console.log(content)
    })
        //here value of content var is empty
    console.log(content)
    showPage(req,res,{'content':content})
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that this is a scoping problem? Could you possibly link to a live version, or try to construct a jsfiddle? I gave it a shot, but didn't find anything helpful

Comment: Of course it's empty, the callback is executed **asynchronous**. Didn't you said that yourself? Or didn't you understand what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `findUser()` is asynchronous (which you indicate), then the issue is that `findUser()` has not yet completed when `showPage()` is called.

For asynchronous functions, you can only use their results from the success handler function.  You can't call an asynchronous function and expect to use it synchronously like your current code.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but this is the general design pattern you would need to use:

```
exports.listUsers=function(req,res) {
    isLoggedIn=user.findUser({},function(myuser) {
         var content = '<li>' + myuser.firstname + ' ' + myuser.lastname + "</li>\n";
         //here value of content var is available
         console.log(content)
         showPage(req,res,{'content':content})
    });
}
```

Or, if the callback is being called many times once for each user, you can accumulate the content and call `showPage()` on the last callback:

```
exports.listUsers=function(req,res) {
    var content = "";
    isLoggedIn=user.findUser({},function(myuser) {
         content += '<li>' + myuser.firstname + ' ' + myuser.lastname + "</li>\n";
         //here value of content var is available
         console.log(content)
         // devise some logic to know when the last callback is being called
         // perhaps based on a user count
         if (this is the last user callback) {
             showPage(req,res,{'content':content})
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: It would not have worked in my case because the anonymous function would have been called one time for each user: the function showPage would have been called multiple times by an each loop returning users one at the time. Instead of the callback, I simplified things and only return the pre-made list - Thanks

Comment: @YounElan - then you would need to accumulate the content like you were doing, but know when the callback is being called for the last time and call `showPage()` then.  I added an example of that to my answer.